# problem in nested Jpanel over Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` and a `Jpanel` over that in which `various buttons` are placed.so **on click of a button** I have called a `new class` which is `also having containers placed in a Jpanel`.so I want to `show` that `new class panel` over the `main Jframe panel`.How can I do that?

And if we use card layout in it then how can i use that as on click button i have called an object of a new class.
as

`Card layout consider each component in a container as card and i want  whole Jpanel as a card so is it possible to do that???`

Can We do nesting of Jpanels in it?

Please suggest me a right way to do that?

here is SSCCE:

```
// this is the  main class on which i want to use panel of other class
public class mymain 
{
    JFrame jframe =  new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout borderlayout = new BorderLayout();

public mymain()
{
    jframe.setLayout(borderlayout);
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    jframe.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JButton home_button = new JButton("HOME");
    menubar.add(home_button);
    jframe.getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);             
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //here used containers over that frame              
             and call it from main()
```

}

```
here is another class to manage category is 

public class manageCategory 
{
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
GridBagLayout gridbglayout = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints gridbgconstraint = new GridBagConstraints();
public manageCategory()
{
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // i have again here used containers placed with grid bag layout
}
```

}

So now i want  that as i `click on home button` used in `mymain` class then the `panel` that is used in `manageCategory()` should be `displayed` on the same panel.and when i again click on `home` button then the `mymain panel` get displayed.how can i do that???

Comment: ..And where is that SSCCE of your best attempt?

Comment: I don't get any idea of using card layout so how can i show SSCCE?

Comment: An SSCCE of this problem could go to the point of creating a `JFrame` and the two (or more) components that are to go in it, then adding a code comment to the effect `// How to use CardLayout to add the components?`  It would also save me (and anyone else who looks to post solutions in the form of code) the trouble of creating that boilerplate code, and allow us to see what sort of components are required for the final code.  But don't stress it, if you could not be bothered showing that much effort, I'll just ignore your further questions.

Comment: What you have given is *not* an SSCCE.  Please read the document!

Comment: hey now i have given wat i want to convey?is it right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for this task.

---

### Updated example with `JPanel` and "classes":

```
static class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel(final Container frame) {
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Click to view next") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.add(new NextPanel(), "NextPanel");
                ((CardLayout) frame.getLayout()).show(frame, "NextPanel");
            }
        }));
    }
}

static class NextPanel extends JPanel {
    public NextPanel() {
        add(new JLabel("Next page in the card layout"));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    frame.add(new MainPanel(frame.getContentPane()), "MainPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: cannot we do nesting of panels in it?

Comment: Yes! Just add a panel and you can do any layout in it. (will update with an example)

Comment: @Geetanjali: Updated example.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
 JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
 JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
 Panel1.setVisible(true);
 myFrame.add(panel1);


 JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
 Panel2.setVisible(false);
 myFrame.add(panel2);

 //Here you setup your panels and your actionlisteners etc and when
 //you wish for your second panel to show up just run the code below.

 panel1.setVisible(false);
 panel2.setVisible(true);
```

Obviously you first have to add both panels to your Jframe. Panel1 will be at first visible, as it is the one shown by default. Panel2 must be set to be invisible in the beginning.

Comment: @kleopatra  Especially true for code intended for public consumption (or that might be worked on by other developers), and *particularly* for code that aims to teach.

Answer (score 1):

CardLayout is one of possible ways, but there are another options valid or required by most completed GUI

1) BorderLayout, because there only one JComponent can occupate decision area

```
someContainer.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER) 
revalidate();
repaint();
```

2) GridBagLayout

before anything you have to get declared [GridBagConstraints](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) from myOldComponent layed by [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)

```
myContainer.setVisible(myOldComponent);
//or
myContainer.remove(myOldComponent);

myContainer.add(myNewComponent, gbc);
revalidate();
repaint();
```